# Recommendations for backend image processing in Python

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

On my site I'm using simple text overlay. Inputs come from textboxes and then javascript makes an AJAX call with the inputs that are then processed in the backend by PIL (Python Imaging Library).

Thing is, I'm not happy about the quality of PIL's text overlays - it's not possible to do a nice looking stroke (e.g. white font color + black stroke) and I'm thinking about switching to a different solution than PIL. I want to stay with Python though.

What would you recommend for image processing in Python? Which library offers the best quality?

Thanks!

Best,
Tom

Comment: If all you're doing is overlaying text, why not use `imagemagick`?

Comment: If your issue with PIL is the aliasing (pixelation), you can oversample. Alternately, have you seen this: http://effbot.org/zone/aggdraw-index.htm

Comment: OpenCV has python bindings and is very powerful

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is overlay text, I suggest you simply use `imagemagick`.